# DTD. Content model is not determenist

Tags: xml, xmllint

I need to your advice. How to describe same elements in alternative choises. For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE offers [
<!ELEMENT offers (offer+)>
<!ELEMENT offer ((name, cost) | (id?, name, tag, desc?) | (prefix, title, desc?))>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cost (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT tag (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT desc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prefix (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
] >

<offers>
    <offer>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <cost>123</cost>
    </offer> 
    <offer>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>Name2</name>
        <tag>sale</tag>
        <desc>Some Description</desc>
    </offer>
    <offer>
        <prefix>Book</prefix>
        <title>Little Pony</title>
    </offer>    
</offers>
```

Tag name repeated in two variants, how to solve this problem during describe elements in dtd.
Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

I think this content model will be the closest to answer your needs:

```
<!ELEMENT offer ((id?, name, (cost | (tag, desc?))) | (prefix, title, desc?)) >
```

However, with this you will also be allowed to insert an `<id>` before the content model with a `<name>` and a `<cost>`, which didn't seem to be the case in your original DTD - but I don't see how it is possible to obtain exactly what your want.

PS: you also need to declare the `id` element in your DTD `<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>`

PS 2: your original document parses correctly with Xerces.